# Pulling Computer Name from Batch File

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a method that allows me to type part of the computer name into a jtextfield and I submit via jbutton. The cmd prompt successfully gives me the full computer name. So if I typed 111255 the command prompt will output coud111255. Query I'm using (@dsquery computer -name *%1)
This part works great. My issue is pulling the full computer name out of the batch file and assigning it to a java variable. I'm trying to append the full computer name to textArea, but it is only pulling the hardcoded value from here:

String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";)

Any Suggestions on how to get the full computer name appended to textArea?

[image]

sendParam() passes half of computer name into batch script to find full computer name.

```
   public static void sendParam(){

          try{
              String val = MISControlPanel.textField.getText(); //Put whatever you want to pass as a prefix in place of "Computer"
                jLabel1.setText(val);
                Process p ;
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat "+val+"");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
```

---

```
StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer(); 
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new       InputStreamReader(p
                            .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        //textArea.append(line);

                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();


                        textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", commonName));
                        //textArea.setText(ComputerQuery.val);

                        selectedComputerFromAD.setText(commonName);
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setForeground(Color.RED);
                        selectedComputerFromAD.setBounds(349, 84, 102, 19);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(selectedComputerFromAD);
                    }
                    ComputerQuery.sendParam();

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e1.printStackTrace();

            } catch (InvalidNameException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally

            {
                try {
                    fw.close();

                }

                catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {

                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e1.printStackTrace();

            }


            ComputerQuery.sendParam();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is `dsquery` the name of a program?  Can you give an example of its exact output?  Also, I can't make out anything in your screenshots.  Is there actually a batch-file involved?

Comment: dsquery is part of the batch file query that finds the computer name. The output to the appended textArea is the FDCD111304 you see in the pic. FDCD111304 over and over again, which is from the hardcoded String dn that I put in parethesis above the pic. If you look at the grey box in the pic you will see this appear over and over again.